# Using Switch Statement in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have to print the multiples of numbers 3 from 80 to 100 by using switch statement

```
echo "Print Numbers Using Switch Statement:<br>";

for ($i=3; $i <= 100 ; $i=$i+3) {

    switch ($i) {
        case "$i >= 80":
            echo $i. "<br>";
            break;

        case "$i <= 100":
            echo $i."<br>";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you even need a switch statement for this? I don't see it's relevancy here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) does not work this way. The **case** must **match** the switch expression.

Change to

```
switch (true)
```

Also remove the quotes off the case expressions.

```
for ($i = 3; $i <= 100; $i += 3) {
    switch (true) {
        case $i >= 80 && $i <= 100:
            echo "$i<br>";
    }
}
```

If you want both statemens as each case you can do like this

```
for ($i = 3; $i <= 100; $i += 3) {
    switch (true) {
        case $i < 80:
            break;
        case $i <= 100:
            echo "$i<br>";
    }
}
```

#### Output

> 81
> 84
> 87
> 90
> 93
> 96
> 99

Comment: Also, It doesn't work

Comment: (Didn't downvote) Why would you wish to have dynamic cases for the switch?

Comment: I don't want to. I just showed it is possible. I guess it is a typical "do my homework" question.

Comment: Ok, but that is a bad practice even if it is possible. Please don't encourage such things.

Comment: @nice_dev The practical use case is doing that when don't want nested or sequential if-statements with possibility to break. Also used in languages that don't have a match keyword. ( PHP now has <3 )

Comment: @Markus Zeller  The Answer is wrong. It should print numbers from 80 to 100 just

Comment: I just corrected your syntax without checking the correctness of the validation. My bad. Answer updated with correction.

Comment: Why answer a question, that doesn't make sense, with an answer that, well, you know, also doesn't make much sense? You can't turn a donkey into a noble steed.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Why not deleting 80% of SO questions at all? As I explained above, there are good reasons using such switch statements.

Comment: I guess our opinions, on what a good reason is, differ. I side with nice_dev: Don't encourage bad programming practices.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Good point. Let's kill python. :)

Comment: I hate snakes, but killing a whole species would be drastic. 